# How to do a fresh install in android studio

Tags: android

From android studio I want to run my app on an android device as if it where the first time running it, ie if I have a DatabaseHelper it will 
run the onCreate method.

Comment: Uninstall the app from the device/emulator or clear its data from the settings app.

Comment: what I do: unistall the application from device and then compile..

Comment: shouldn't the title of question be "How to fresh install app in an Android device"?

Answer (score 7):

Android Studio (`Intellij`) has ability to add step into build process.

1. Select `Run` menu and select `Edit Configurations`
2. Duplicate `debug` configuration and call it `uninstall and debug`
3. Then at the same window there is part `Before launch`
4. Click on `plus` icon and choose `Run External tool`:
   [image]
5. Then add new one.
6. Locate `adb` and add into `parameters` field next params: `shell pm uninstall <com.your.package>`
   [image]
7. Thats all. When you choose this configuration `Android Studio` will uninstall your app, then build brand new `apk` file, install it and launch debug mode.

Comment: These options don't exist anymore, how would you do it in AS 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Delete data: settings / applications / select your app / delete data